# create json structure for in wcf(dynamic key for json)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How to declare dynamic key using class?

```
{
"balls": {"a8bf081d-eaef-44db-ba25-97ed8c0b30ef": {"team": {"runs": 1,
          "extras": 0,
          "ball_count": 1,
          "wicket": 0
        }
      },
}}
```

Comment: You should give a better definition to your Json and object. Because his is not a valid Json. And there is a lot of difference between the 1rst code you post and this one. The easiest way is to work with a `Dictionary<string, myCustomObj> Foos`

Comment: Search for the other way around you will find easy to do a serialisation of those object once you have done a deserialisation on a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last Json format, still not valid but close. 
You have the following class

```
public class Team
{
    public int runs { get; set; }
    public int extras { get; set; }
    public int ball_count { get; set; }
    public int wicket { get; set; }
}
```

Using a `Dictionary<string, Team>` you can simply:

```
var objFoo = new
{
    balls = new Dictionary<string, Team>
    {
        {
            "a8bf081d-eaef-44db-ba25-97ed8c0b30ef",
            new Team{
                runs=1,
                extras=0,
                ball_count=1,
                wicket=0
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objFoo);
```

[online Exemple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cJGy3D)